# Client Side, to API, POST http... net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, backend, web-development-server

I have made a basic https response sending data in JSON format from the client to the API at a particular endpoint named /api on my a2 web server. For some reason, the connection refuses and nothing ends up getting logged to the terminal I access through SSH.

Server Sided Code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.listen(3000,()=>console.log('listening on port 3000'));
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.post('/api',(request,response)=>
{
    console.log(request);
});
```

Page to be served client sided:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
        console.log("Page started");
            const num1=1;
            const num2=2;
            const data=35;//{num1,num2};
            const options =
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers:
                {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            };
            fetch(/*'https://goldengates.club:3000/api'*/'https://goldengates.club:3000/api',options);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Error Message on served client sided page:

```
Page started
(index):22 POST https://goldengates.club:3000/api net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
(anonymous) @ (index):22
goldengates.club/:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

I am aware that there are major security flaws, this is only to get familiar with particular functions I have never used.

Answer (score 0):

In the Client-side change API base URL instead of https://goldengates.club:3000/api use given below:

```
https://goldengates.club/api
```

please try this one.
 HTTP… net:: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT Error: the reason is your Request URL Not be able to Found a path. we not a need use DOMAIN NAME + PORT (https://goldengates.club:3000)

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that is incorrect. The server side is running on port 3000 and it needs to be specified. Also it gives me error 404: ```(index):22 POST https://goldengates.club/api 404```

Comment: please can you check your domain pointed with your server-side code properly not  server code path e.g  cd  /root/home/projects/server/ProjectFolder  check that domain is pointed with this particular path & Listening to this  PORT or not. Error reason is requested URL  is not Found. because your domain is not able to point you specific folder path

Comment: please add on in the API Methof inside Response :                                                              response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");response.send({  
        statusCode:200,
        customMessage : 'Sucess',
        status : true
    })

Comment: so you want me to put the correct directory for the server sided code? https://goldengates.club/Cypher-Network/fetchTest.js ? What about the endpoint I made for the API to take requests?

Comment: we don't need to use a Domain + PORT because our Domain is Already run on a Particular PORT. Please don't mind but you can check Any Website no one use domainName + PORT.   Thanks:)

Comment: exactly, check that the correct directory for the server-sided code.and the Lil Bit changes in API endpoint I above mentioned that render in the return success response.

Comment: ```app.post('/api',(request,response)=>
{
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");response.send({ statusCode:200, customMessage : 'Sucess', status : true }) 
    
    console.log(request);
});``` in server sided code, ```https://goldengates.club/Cypher-Network/fetchTest.js``` As the fetch location, no errors on index.js console, but the data yet did not pass through to my server sided code, since it sends requests to the /api endpoint.

Comment: please don't mind I have already checked that your code and hit your API Endpoint in the postman.[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TVihvn7hjxcBmyHFOymtMbHBqGK9BR2d/view] and I got the result request URL not Found reason Above I mentioned. I say that because I have to face this issue in many Times and resolved

Comment: just to be clear, you tried accessing goldengates.club/Cypher-Network/fetchTest.js right? or did you try accessing goldengates.club:3000/api? Don't forget that the endpoint /api can only be accessed locally as it is local to the server. So maybe that is my problem when client side tries sending requests to a local endpoint to the server. If that is the case how can I change the architecture so it works.

Comment: ya, I am checking as a testing purpose.use this Base Url (https://goldengates.club/api).  what's an Error exactly.

Comment: vivek, I edited the post where I asked which url you tried accessing I am sure the architecture itself is the flaw.

Answer (score 0):

You are not ending the request properly in your express application. You need to call `response.end();`

Comment: I should always send a response or end it yes, but the problem persists, thank you for your response though.